# script line does not pop up and does not register to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Can anyone please help me with my code i registered it to my localhost but the script does not pop up and it does not register to my database.

by the way this is a search engine I'm making thank you for your answers.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br>
        <center>
            <h2><b> Insert Website</b></h2></center>
        <br>
        <form action="insert_site.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" for="stitle"> Site title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" is="stitle" name="s_title" placeholder="Enter Site Title">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" for="slink"> Site link</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" is="slink" name="s_link" placeholder="Enter Site Link">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <br>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" for="skey"> Site key</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" is="skey" name="s_key" placeholder="Enter Site key">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" for="sdes"> Site Description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" is="sdes" name="s_des" placeholder="Enter Site Description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2" for="simg"> Site Image</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" is="simg" name="s_img" placeholder="Enter Site Image">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <center>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="submit" value="Add Website"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger" name="submit" value="Cancel">
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajaz/libs/kquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pyDQGamwU6poAc/hOdqxjnoEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+41GLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script tsrc="https://odnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbewg8JY28KFelvJVai01l0WyZzrYWG825m+oZOeDDS1f7d/js61kvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

 <?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "search");
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo htmlentities($row['_message']);


    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
         $s_title = $_POST["s_title"];
         $s_link = $_POST["s_link"];
         $s_key = $_POST["s_key"];
         $s_des = $_POST["s_des"];
         $_simg = $_FILES["simg"] ["name"];

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["simg"] ["tmp_name"], "img/".  $_FILES["simg"] ["name"]))
    {
        $sql = "insert into website(site_title, site_link, site_key, site_des, site_img) values('$s_title','$s_link','$s_key','$s_des','$s_img')";

        $rs = mysqli_query($sql);

        if($rs)
        {
            echo"<script> alert('Site uploaded Successfully') </script>";
        }

        else
        {
            echo"<script> alert('Uploaded failed please try again')</script>";
        }


    }
}



 ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Please just remove the echoon the php

Comment: Does it return any error messages?

Comment: Errors might be silenced by default in the server configuration. Here is a thread on enabling error reporting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/5169684

Comment: it does not show script whether it was saved or not

Answer (score 0):

I sow only this mistake.

```
echo $_simg = $_FILES...
```

I think you need to change in

```
INSERT INTO : ... '$s_img');
```

Comment: sorry forgot  to remove the echo

Comment: can you please explain to me more i'm new to php so i don't get it